# How to present GKMatchmakerViewController to presented view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I'm implementing real time game center into my game and I have problem with presenting `GKMatchmakerViewController`. Here is my situation:

1. There is HomeViewController in which I'm presenting `GameViewController` with next code:

   ```
    GameViewController *gameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil];
    gameViewController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:gameViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
   ```
2. Then in `GameViewController` I include `GCHelper` and call to game center to start match:

   ```
   -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

   {
       [super viewDidAppear:animated];


       [[GCHelper sharedInstance] authenticateLocalUser];

       [[GCHelper sharedInstance] findMatchWithMinPlayers:2 maxPlayers:2 viewController:self delegate:(id)self];


   }
   ```

And problem is that that small alert from game center that I'm back again is showed:
[image]

but big window of game center is not shown. I'm sure that problem is in that that I'm presenting `GameViewController`.

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE:**

When I try to call Game Center in HomeViewConroller, everything works perfect.

**UPDATE 2 (tried):**
I tried in GCHelper instead:

```
[presentingViewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

use:

```
AppDelegate * appdelegate = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appdelegate.homeViewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but then I get error:
 **whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

Comment: actually login is showing when you are not login in game, according to graphics you are already login

Comment: Correct, but with this code there must be shown Game center: [[GCHelper sharedInstance] findMatchWithMinPlayers:2 maxPlayers:2 viewController:self delegate:(id)self];

Comment: i am sending whole code to you

Comment: [[GCHelper sharedInstance] authenticateLocalUser];

Comment: the problem is you're calling the findMatch method right after the authenticate method. Most probably when game center still haven't had the chance to authenticate the user. Ideally you should authenticate the user when the user first launches the app. Or if you use GC only for this purpose, you can call findMatch method in your authentication completion block (which is an uglier solution).

Comment: AppController * delegate = (AppController *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [[GCHelper sharedInstance] findMatchWithMinPlayers:2 maxPlayers:2 viewController:delegate.viewController];

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu - no, that's not the problem. I tried tu put to HomeViewController and there is working everythingk ok. Problem is with presented GameViewController like I said in title of my question.

Comment: @CroiOS then it's weird because I'm successfully presenting a matchmakerviewcontroller on a presented view controller using the same method that you use. (but I authenticate on appdelegate applicationdidlaunch method, give that a try too..)

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu - tried :(

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu - can you please post on some service your code how do you presenting in your code, please?

Comment: would you like to service means

Comment: or you can contact me on kalimullah.sheikh on skypee

Comment: if my code is helpful for you . you can up vote me.

Comment: Found problem; [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22580/discussion-between-mohd-kalimullah-sheikh-and-croios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was **[presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];**

I should remove dismissViewController and than everything was okay.

```
//[presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]; // that I removed

GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
request.minPlayers = minPlayers;
request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
request.playersToInvite = pendingPlayersToInvite;

GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

[presentingViewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];

self.pendingInvite = nil;
self.pendingPlayersToInvite = nil;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
GCHelper.h


//
//  GCHelper.h
//  KvK
//
//  Created by Kalim on 11/22/12.
//
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <GameKit/Gamekit.h>

@interface GCHelper : NSObject<GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate, GKMatchDelegate>
{
    BOOL isUserAuthenticated;

    UIViewController *presentingViewController;
    GKMatch *match;
    BOOL matchStarted;

    GKInvite *pendingInvite;
    NSArray *pendingPlayersToInvite;
    NSMutableDictionary *playersDict;

    NSString *MultiplayerID;
    NSData *MultiData;
    NSString *otherPlayerID;

    char AlertMessageBoxNo;

    BOOL isDataRecieved;
}

//variables

@property (assign, readonly) BOOL gameCenterAvailable;
@property (retain) UIViewController *presentingViewController;
@property (retain) GKMatch *match;
@property (retain) GKInvite *pendingInvite;
@property (retain) NSArray *pendingPlayersToInvite;
@property (retain) NSMutableDictionary *playersDict;

@property (retain) NSString *MultiplayerID;
@property (retain) NSData *MultiData;

-(NSString*)getOtherPlayerId;
-(void)setOtherPlayerId;
//Functions
+ (GCHelper *)sharedInstance;
-(BOOL)isGameCenterAvailable;
-(void)authenticationChanged;
-(void)authenticateLocalUser;

-(void)gameOver:(NSString*)message;

-(void)setDataRecieved:(BOOL)d;
-(BOOL)getDataRecieved;


- (void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;

@end

GCHelper.mm


//
//  GCHelper.m
//  KvK
//
//  Created by Kalim on 11/22/12.
//
//

#import "GCHelper.h"
#import "IPadSharebleClass.h"


@implementation GCHelper

@synthesize gameCenterAvailable;
@synthesize presentingViewController;
@synthesize match;
@synthesize pendingInvite;
@synthesize pendingPlayersToInvite;
@synthesize playersDict;
@synthesize MultiData;
@synthesize MultiplayerID;

static GCHelper *sharedHelper = nil;

+(GCHelper *) sharedInstance
{
    if (!sharedHelper)
    {
        sharedHelper = [[GCHelper alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedHelper;
}


- (BOOL)isGameCenterAvailable
{
    Class gcClass = (NSClassFromString(@"GKLocalPlayer"));
    NSString *reqSysVer = @"4.1";
    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    BOOL osVersionSupported = ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending);
    return (gcClass && osVersionSupported);
}


- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        gameCenterAvailable = [self isGameCenterAvailable];
        if (gameCenterAvailable)
        {
            NSNotificationCenter *nc =
            [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
            [nc addObserver:self
                   selector:@selector(authenticationChanged)
                       name:GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName
                     object:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Game Center Alert" message:@"Game Center Not Available" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)authenticationChanged
{
    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated && !isUserAuthenticated)
    {
        NSLog(@"Authentication changed: player authenticated.");
        isUserAuthenticated = TRUE;

        [GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite)
        {
            NSLog(@"Received invite");
            self.pendingInvite = acceptedInvite;
            self.pendingPlayersToInvite = playersToInvite;
            IPadCallAnyWhereF.inviteReceived();
        };

    }
    else if (![GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated && isUserAuthenticated)
    {
        NSLog(@"Authentication changed: player not authenticated");
        isUserAuthenticated = FALSE;
    }


}

- (void)authenticateLocalUser
{
    if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

    NSLog(@"Authenticating local user...");
    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO)
    {
        [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Already authenticated!");
    }
}

-(void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

    matchStarted = NO;
    self.match = nil;
    self.presentingViewController = viewController;
    if (pendingInvite != nil)
    {
        [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:pendingInvite] autorelease];
        mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
        [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];

        self.pendingInvite = nil;
        self.pendingPlayersToInvite = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        request.minPlayers = minPlayers;
        request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
        request.playersToInvite = pendingPlayersToInvite;

        GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
        mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

        [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];

        self.pendingInvite = nil;
        self.pendingPlayersToInvite = nil;

    }

}


#pragma mark GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate
- (void)matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController
{
    [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Game Center Alert" message:@"Game Cancel By you" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again" otherButtonTitles:@"Main Menu", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    AlertMessageBoxNo='E';
}

- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Error finding match: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Game Center Alert" message:@"Connection Time out" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again" otherButtonTitles:@"Main Menu", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    AlertMessageBoxNo='A';
}


- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *)theMatch
{
    [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.match = theMatch;
    match.delegate = self;
    if (!matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"***************Ready to start match!**************");
        [self lookupPlayers];
    }
}

- (void)lookupPlayers
{
    NSLog(@"Looking up %d players...", match.playerIDs.count);
    [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:match.playerIDs withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error != nil)
         {
             NSLog(@"Error retrieving player info: %@", error.localizedDescription);
             matchStarted = NO;
             //IPadCallAnyWhereF.matchEnded();
             UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Game Center Alert" message:@"Error retrieving player info" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again" otherButtonTitles:@"Main Menu", nil];
             [alert show];
             [alert release];
             AlertMessageBoxNo='F';
         }
         else
         {
             self.playersDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:players.count];
             for (GKPlayer *player in players)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Found player: %@", player.alias);
                 [playersDict setObject:player forKey:player.playerID];
             }
             NSLog(@"Total Number of Players : %d",players.count);
             matchStarted = YES;
             IPadCallAnyWhereF.matchStarted();
         }
     }];

}

#pragma mark GKMatchDelegate
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)theMatch didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID
{
    if (match != theMatch) return;

    MultiData=data;
    MultiplayerID=playerID;
    if(otherPlayerID==nil)
    {
        otherPlayerID=[playerID retain];
    }
    IPadCallAnyWhereF.match();
}

-(void)setDataRecieved:(BOOL)d
{
    isDataRecieved=d;
}
-(BOOL)getDataRecieved
{
    return isDataRecieved;
}


-(NSString*)getOtherPlayerId
{
    return otherPlayerID;
}

-(void)setOtherPlayerId
{
    otherPlayerID=nil;
}

- (void)match:(GKMatch *)theMatch player:(NSString *)playerID didChangeState:(GKPlayerConnectionState)state
{
    if (match != theMatch) return;
    switch (state)
    {
        case GKPlayerStateConnected:
            NSLog(@"New Player connected!");
            if (!matchStarted && theMatch.expectedPlayerCount == 0)
            {
                NSLog(@"&&&&&&&&&& Ready to start match in the match!");
                [self lookupPlayers];
            }
            break;
        case GKPlayerStateDisconnected:
            NSLog(@"--------Player disconnected!--------");
            matchStarted = NO;
            UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Game Center Alert" message:@"Player Disconnected" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again" otherButtonTitles:@"Main Menu", nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            AlertMessageBoxNo='B';
            //IPadCallAnyWhereF.matchDisconnect();
            break;
    }
}

- (void)match:(GKMatch *)theMatch connectionWithPlayerFailed:(NSString *)playerID withError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (match != theMatch) return;

    NSLog(@"Failed to connect to player with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    matchStarted = NO;
    //IPadCallAnyWhereF.matchEnded();
    UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Game Center Alert" message:@"Failed to connect to player" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again" otherButtonTitles:@"Main Menu", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    AlertMessageBoxNo='C';

}

- (void)match:(GKMatch *)theMatch didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (match != theMatch) return;

    NSLog(@"Match failed with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    matchStarted = NO;
    //IPadCallAnyWhereF.matchEnded();
    UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Game Center Alert" message:@"Match failed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again" otherButtonTitles:@"Main Menu", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    AlertMessageBoxNo='D';

}

-(void)gameOver:(NSString*)message
{
    UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Game Center Alert" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again" otherButtonTitles:@"Main Menu", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    AlertMessageBoxNo='G';
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Try Again"])
    {
        IPadCallAnyWhereF.matchDisconnect();
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Main Menu"])
    {
        IPadCallAnyWhereF.gotoMainMenu();
    }

}



@end
```